# Pandas DataFrame: column cumsum divide by total sum of rows & columns to date

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to divide the cumulative sum of values across columns by the total sum of values across rows and columns for a given date.

My DataFrame has the following input:

```
            UHIU   FVZJ   VTJS
2000-11-11  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
2000-11-12  0.0000 0.0000 0.1000
2000-11-13  0.0000 1.0000 0.3000
2000-11-14  0.0000 0.2000 0.0000
```

The expected output is as follow:

```
            UHIU   FVZJ   VTJS
2000-11-11  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
2000-11-12  0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
2000-11-13  0.0000 0.7143 0.2857
2000-11-14  0.0000 0.7500 0.2500
```

The logic works as follow: FVZJ has a value of 1.0000 in 2000-11-13, the desired outcome involves calculating the cumulative sum of FVZJ's values between 200-11-11 (included) and 2000-11-13 (included) (i.e. 1.0000), and dividing the result by the cumulative sum of UHIU, FVZJ, and VTJS's values between 2000-11-11 (included) and 2000-11-13 (included) (i.e. 1.4000)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.cumsum().div(df.sum(1).cumsum(),0).fillna(0) # notice first row will return NaN, since x/0 mean nothing.
Out[846]: 
            UHIU      FVZJ      VTJS
2000-11-11   0.0  0.000000  0.000000
2000-11-12   0.0  0.000000  1.000000
2000-11-13   0.0  0.714286  0.285714
2000-11-14   0.0  0.750000  0.250000
```